# Passthrough Printer Driver

Tags: windows, printing

I have Windows XP machine which is part of a Windows domain and is able to printer to the printers on the same domain. I'm trying to expose one of these printers through one of the TCP ports on this machine so that the machine not on the domain or even on the same network can use this printer through this TCP port. In other words, I'm thinking if there is any way to install a program on my computer that listens to a port and acts as a "passthrough printer driver". Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Install the printer on your computer as a local printer on the tcp/ip port.
Once installed, share the printer with permissions allowing everyone and anonymous access.
Connect to the shared printer with the 2nd computer.

Comment: I do not have access to the printer sharing settings. The logged in user on my machine has access to this printer and I just want to have a program to emulate a TCP port on my machine and pass the data to the network printer. Then on the remote machine, I can install the local printer on the TCP/IP ports of my machine which is acting as a printer.